# In android, how can I pass multiple FileURIs/Paths in the order I have selected the files?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I intend to pass multiple file-URIs/Paths to my Activity using intent. I have the necessary code in place (i.e. `SEND_MULTIPLE` in Manifest and `getIntent()` in Activity) and I am able to get the file-list from the `intent` in my Activity. However, this file-list is sorted in alphabetical order and not in the same order as I selected my files from Gallery.

Is there a way to get the file-list in same order as I select the files in Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid to tell you that it seems like, there are no way to ensure the sorting order of the data send using the `Intent`. That's why you have to do it by yourself.

I do recommend for you to create a [`Parcelable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1364896) object contain two things (int order, String url). Then send the list of the `Parcelable` objects using the `intent`. Then implement a simple [`comparator`](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) to sort those object after retrieving them using the `order` attribute